How to optimise Fe-Cu ratio for Fenton-like oxidation of methylene blue dye?
I'm using different ratios of Fe-Cu homogenous catalysts where both metals are +2 charge (0:100, 20:80, 40:60, 60:40, 80:20, 100:0) to catalyse Fenton reaction that will oxidise the methylene blue dye.
If the degradation extent does not show a linear (or any specific trend), how do you explain this in chemical terms? Should I calculate the amounts of Fe and Cu to find the ideal optimum ratio?
And, what should I do if the $\ce{Fe^2+}$ is oxidised to $\ce{Fe^3+}$ prior to the reaction? How would I determine how much iron has been oxidised and take that into consideration when making my conclusion?

It might expose the kinetic patterns better, if you try rather few series with [Cu] variable and [Fe] constant.
